# Unable to load app with protractor test runner

Tags: google-chrome, integration-testing, protractor

I am new to AngularJS. I'm trying to run end-to-end tests with Protractor. Currently, I am running my tests from grunt with help from grunt-protractor-runner. My base test looks like the following:

```
describe('My Tests', function () {
    var p = protractor.getInstance();

    beforeEach(function () {
    });

    it('My First Test', function () {
        var message = "Hello!";
        expect(message).toEqual('Hello!');
    });
});
```

This works just fine. However, it really doesn't test my app. To do that I always want to start in the root of the app. In an attempt to do this, I've updated the above to the following:

```
describe('My Tests', function () {
    var p = protractor.getInstance();

    beforeEach(function () {
        p.get('#/');
    });

    it('My First Test', function () {
        var message = "Hello!";
        expect(message).toEqual('Hello!');
    });
});
```

When this test gets ran, Chrome launches. However, "about:blank" is what gets loaded in the address bar. My app never loads. I've reviewed my protractor.config.js file and it looks correct. It looks like the following:

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

    seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/bin/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar',
    seleniumPort: 1234,
    seleniumArgs: [],
    seleniumAddress: null,

    chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/bin/selenium/chromedriver.exe',
    capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome' },

    specs: [ '../tests/**/*.spec.js' ],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
};
```

How do I get my app to load into Chrome for the purpose of an integration test via protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've already figured out how to get it working, but if not maybe the following will help (modify the port if necessary of course):

```
// A base URL for your application under test. Calls to protractor.get()
// with relative paths will be prepended with this.
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
```

Add this property to your protractor.config.js file.

Reference: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/referenceConf.js